exams:::exams2pdf throws an error related to sh
When I try to use exams2pdf (e.g., exams2pdf("boxplots.Rmd")) from the exams package I get the following error:

sh: line 1: : command not found

I can execute usual terminal commands within R using system(), for example:

system("ls # list files and folders in WD")

What am I missing? Why can't exams2pdf() use the shell (bash, I assume) correctly? I am using Linux.
Thank you in advance.

That example works for me.  You need to give more information to diagnose what is going wrong on your system.  Try exams2pdf("boxplots.Rmd", verbose = TRUE) and after the error, traceback().  If that doesn't make the issue obvious to you, cut and paste the output into your question.

Source of the problem: The exams2pdf() function tries to open the PDF file it has produced in a PDF viewer. I suspect that R finds a wrong or non-existing path for your PDF viewer.
Workaround: As a quick workaround you can tell exams2pdf() to write the PDF file to a directory where you can open it yourself. For example, to create the file in your current working directory use
 exams2pdf("boxplots.Rmd", dir = ".")

And then you can open plain1.pdf yourself.
Debugging: When you have created the plain1.pdf file using the code above you can try to open it from R just like R/exams does. On Linux, it takes the following steps:
out <- "plain1.pdf"                      ## PDF file in current directory
vwr <- getOption("pdfviewer")            ## path to your systems's PDF viewer
cmd <- paste(shQuote(vwr), shQuote(out)) ## PDF viewer command to be executed
system(cmd, wait = FALSE)                ## run PDF viewer command

On my system the viewer path vwr and the resulting quoted command cmd look as follows:
writeLines(c(vwr, cmd))
## /usr/bin/xpdf
## '/usr/bin/xpdf' 'plain1.pdf'

I suspect that your PDF viewer is somehow misconfigured...

Achim, you found my problem. getOption("pdfviewer") was empty in my case. I added the R environment variable R_PDFVIEWER with the value /usr/bin/okular to .Renviron in my home folder. And that was it, R now can find Okular and exams2pdf() works as expected.
Many thanks for solving my problem (also to @user2554330, thank you).

Thanks for the follow-up, I will try to add a check for this with a more informative error message.

W.r.t. paths I prefer file.path() over paste().

Me too. Note that paste() is used to combine the function name and the file name into a single command. So file.path() would not work here.

I have added an explicit check and intelligible warning message for this in the development version on R-Forge now.
